# When in Journey Builder what is the difference between journey data and contact data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am creating a JB with an engagement split. What is the difference between Contact Data and Journey Data. ie what will I see listed in the two groupings. If I choose the journey data will this only be as up to date as the time that the data entered the Journey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Journey Data is the data at the state of the contact entering the journey. In contrast contact data is the state of data at the time you are using it, even if it changed since journey start.

> Journey data preserves the state of a contact's data at the moment an entry event fires, facilitating the use of that data throughout a journey. Contact data captures the data values in the event source data extension at the time when Journey Builder evaluates it.
>
> **Journey Data:**
>
> - Initial data value about a customer
> - Provides attributes in the state they were in when the contact entered the journey
> - Comprised of event data and activity data
> - Use when a contact is likely to exist in a journey more than once simultaneously
> - Use for comparison when a data value is expected to change
>
> **Contact Data:**
>
> - Current data value about a customer
> - Provides attributes in the state they are in when evaluation occurs after the entry event has fired
>
> (Source: [Journey and Contact Data](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/))

**Related documentation:**

- [Journey and Contact Data](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/)
- [Use Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/use_event_data_in_decision_splits/)

Comment: Thanks that's great this confirms what I would need to use in the journey for my engagement split. Thanks!