# Journey Builder is not pulling the correct data from data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio

I have a journey which is not pulling data from our data extension correctly.

The data in the data extension is correct but the email that has been sent out has a previous value.

I update the data extension using an automation, pulling data from salesforce via sql and the data updates in there as expected. The journey fires 5 minutes after the automation is run.

The emails in the journey are about a month apart so timing shouldn't be affecting this.

The "DevLaunchDate" in the data extension is the example that hasn't changed. It should say "Early 2020" but the email states "October 2019".

Data extension: 
[image]

[image]

Email:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you pulling in the field? Lookup function or just as a personalization string?

Comment: Just a personalisation string.

Comment: Ah - personalization strings will by default use 'Journey Data' (snapshot of the fields, detailed in the answers below). You'll need to use a Lookup for the most up-to-date values for all fields. Here's a link more specific to email: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_personalization_in_the_journey_builder_send_email_activity.htm&type=5

Comment: @AnonWonderer - great thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use CONTACT DATA rather than Journey DATA!

For more info on this please find details here: [When in Journey Builder what is the difference between journey data and contact data?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191464/when-in-journey-builder-what-is-the-difference-between-journey-data-and-contact)

Where in you need to relate your DE to the CONTACT model.

Comment: @Emma Yeah, using Journey Data takes a snapshot of your data at entry and no matter what changes you make to it after are not reflected in this data set. Using Contact Data will allow your data to be edited and the changes reflected inside the Journey. The caveat being that using Contact Data is slower and less stable (data can be removed, potentially causing errors or failures) than Journey Data. You can also change your email to pull via a Lookup() instead and this will allow it to pull in the updated info.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am using contact data which is why this problem is so strange. Support are struggling with it too

Comment: Wow!... thanks @Gortonington for sharing the trick, a simple AMPscript function 'Lookup()' will do the trick! I was NOT aware of this.